# Generic Typescript Method to return any of the Object key types or Object type itself based on input

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics, functional-interface

I want to define a typescript method where method could return a type of Object or any property of the Object.
e.g

```
Person {
   Education,
   Bio
}
```

Generic function could return either `Person` or `Education` or `Bio` based on the input provided lets say Enum for type.

```
let person = testFunction(TypePerson); // complete person 

let personEducation = testFunction(TypeEducation); // person's education
```

Person type is just for example but here could be anything and properties will not be known in advance.

e.g instead of Person lets say got

```
Vehicle {
  PropertyType1,
  SomeProperties
}
```

Comment: could you please share what are you exactly expect?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking about function overloading.

```js
interface Person {
  Education: string;
  Age: number;
}

interface Vehicle {
  doors: number;
  color: 'pink' | 'red';
}

enum Data {
  person = 'person',
  car = 'car'
}

function getData(data: Data.car): Vehicle
function getData(data: Data.person): Person
function getData(data: Data) {
  return 'your implementation' as any
}

const result1 = getData(Data.person) //Person
const result2 = getData(Data.car) //Vehicle
```

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) you can find more info